# Hide checkbox until mouse over WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, triggers, ismouseover

I am new to XAML, but I would like the `CheckBox` option to be hidden on my application until the user mouses over the row and can check the box from there. Here is what I currently have and I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Name="cbkSelect" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectedForOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbkSelect, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </CheckBox.Style>
      </CheckBox>
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the `CheckBox` only if a user hovers the **row**, meaning any cell of a row, you can use a `RelativeSource` binding to the `IsMouseOver` property the parent row.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you want it to be dislayed only if a user hovers over the `CheckBox` column, your style will not work as you do not receive the mouse events on a hidden control. You can work around this with a `Border` that is visible.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border x:Name="cbkBorder" Background="Transparent">
            <CheckBox Name="cbkSelect" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectedForOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
               <CheckBox.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbkBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
               </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!!!!!! The first solution is exactly what I was looking for! Really appreciate it :D

Comment: how would you recommend I get the checkbox to stay visible once the row is checked? Booltovisibility converter?

Comment: @AlexJohnson Sorry, I did not check your message. I have already answered your new question about that, which is basically adding a `Trigger` for  the `IsChecked` property.